Не получается изменить цвет фона камеры в Unity
Не получается изменить цвет фона у камеры с именем "MainCamera".
Код:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeCameraBGScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string Type;
    public void OnClick()
    {
        if (Type == "GameBG") { Debug.Log("Camera BG changed to 25, 2, 34 (By Type GameBG)"); GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color(25, 2, 34); }
    }
}


Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке изменения цвета фона камеры в Unity используется неверный формат для передачи цвета. В коде для установки цвета камеры new Color(25, 2, 34) используются значения, которые не входят в допустимый диапазон (от 0 до 1). Нужно нормализовать значения RGB до этого диапазона. Например, изменить код на:
GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color(25f / 255f, 2f / 255f, 34f / 255f);

